# Close application when it is unused for some time

Tags: vb.net

I am developing an application in vb.net and I would like to be able to tell if the user is on the main form but did not do anything for a moment. 
Is there any way to check if the user is using or not the application and to logout if not?

I've made some searches on it and I got no conclusions if I could develop this code... So you have any idea on how I should solve this?

Comment: Commonly, you use a timer.  Every so often, the timer routine checks to see if a certain flag has been raised.  If so, it resets the flag and starts the timer again.  Otherwise, it terminates the application.  Other parts of the code that "do something" constantly set that flag.  *But, remember,* you must let the timer run *twice.*  (A one-minute timer could wake up two seconds from now.)  How to arrange that, ought to be clear.

Comment: Add a handler to every control (when control recieved focus) on that form that would set/ add to a variable. When control gains focus set a variable of type integer to plus 1. Use a timer to check how often you want if something has happened, if nothing has happened close the application, otherwise reset that variable back to 0... Since you did not provide anything for us to help you we can't extend our help in helping you. We help with specific problems, but there are a few options to get you started already mentioned.

Comment: Yes, thanks for you advice. I didn't provide anything because as I said I search and I haven't found anything @Zaggler

Comment: @IGottaGo Welcome, if you should get stuck on something specific come back and we would be glad to help!

Comment: @zaggler is on the right path, but don't add a handler to every control. That's way too much work, and has other costs. Just subscribe to the `Application.Idle` event, and run your timer in response to that event.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a class with a timer which will monitor updates and end execution if needed.

```
Public Class IdleWatcher
    ' TODO: Implements IDisposable
    ' TODO: and dispose _timer
    Private _timer As System.Threading.Timer
    Private _enabled As Boolean
    Private _lastEvent As DateTime
    Public Sub New()
        _timer = New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf watch)
        _enabled = False
        Timeout = 0
    End Sub
    Public Event Idle(sender As Object)
    Public Property Timeout As Long
    Public Property Enabled As Boolean
        Get
            Return _enabled
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            If value Then
                _lastEvent = DateTime.Now
                _timer.Change(0, 1000)
            Else
                _timer.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Sub watch()
        If DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastEvent).TotalMilliseconds > Timeout Then
            Enabled = false
            ' raise an event so the form can handle it and log out
            RaiseEvent Idle(Me)
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub Refresh()
        _lastEvent = DateTime.Now
    End Sub
End Class
```

It can be used in your forms application like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents watcher As New IdleWatcher
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        watcher.Timeout = 5000 ' 5 second timeout
        watcher.Enabled = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
        watcher.Refresh()
    End Sub
    Private Sub watcher_idle(sender As Object) Handles watcher.Idle
        ' If login.show is modal, then you don't need to call MainForm.Close()
        ' This will depend on your implementation
        Login.Show()
        MainForm.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This will at least monitor mouse movement on Form1. If you want to share the instance across multiple forms so you can Refresh it from other forms, you can make the class a singleton. It's a good candidate for one.

Depending on how thorough you want to be, you can also call Refresh from event handlers of other controls such as TextBoxes and Buttons on your forms.

Even further, you could subclass all your controls and add a Refresh call in all relevant UI event handlers in the base classes. This would save a lot of work if you find yourself Refreshing all over the place.

Comment: I like you method. But I can change it to instead of closing terminate the application basically just logout and displays another form right?

Comment: Yes of course. You can define an Event in the IdleWatcher class and handle it in your main form, and log out. Raise the event instead of calling End.

Comment: But I just need to make that changes on IdleWatcher class right?

Comment: Updated my answer according to your comments. Added event to the IdleWatcher class, raised it on idle, handled event in the form.

Comment: So, if I want to make the main form close and open the login form I should change the MessageBox.Show("I am idle") to Login.Show()?

Comment: I can't presume to know what your code looks like. You can decide what to do in the idle event. I guess you would want to do Login.Show(), as well as closing your other form(s).

Comment: Imagine, I am on the main form where everything happens. The user isn't using the app for quite sometime so what I want to do is basaclly log out and show the Login form. You know what I mean?

Comment: I understand what you want to do. I just can't provide much more development for you pro bono. Especially when I get two downvotes without reason, and no love, just for trying to help a newbie.

Comment: Ok don't help. That is not my problem... If you don't wanna help and you are thinking a lot about that haters....

Comment: Have you even +1'd my answer brother? This is not a charity :)

Comment: I've tried but I'm 14 reputation. And if you gave me the correct anwser I will give you the credit of course

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code looks like. If you put some of your source code in the question it might help. Maybe you can do `Login.Show()`, but what would you do with the main form? Do you need to hide it or freeze it? I'm not sure. Wouldn't you need to make functionality available to exit the application instead of logging back in? Then wouldn't it need to be non-modal / and you'd need to restrict access to the ui somehow. Too many unanswered questions to provide a complete solution.

Comment: The code that I could provide to you is just useless for what I am looking for...The goal of this piece of code as you helped me with your code, if user is not working with the app it will logout(or MainForm.Close()) and Login.Show()